# Rails: param is missing or the value is empty because param appearing as "#<Edge:0xb2535b8>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm using form for and the name of the form in the controller is appearing as "#", but I expect it to appear as :edge.

Here's my controller:

```
  def new
      #some_stuff
      @edge = Edge.new
      #some_stuff
  end

  def create
    @edge = Edge.new(edge_params)
    @edge.save
  end

  def edge_params
    params.require(:edge).permit(:location_1_id, :location_2_id)
  end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for( :edge, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <%= f.label :location_1_id %>
      <%= collection_select(@edge, :location_1_id, @location, :id, :record_as_string) %>
    </li>
    <%= submit_tag(t(:create_edge)) %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Param req:

> {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blah",
>   "#"=>{"location_1_id"=>"91", "location_2_id"=>"92"},
>   "commit"=>"Create Edge", "action"=>"create",
>   "controller"=>"admin/edges", "floor_map_floor_id"=>"1"}

So the  name of the parameter should be :edge but it's an object that I can't access.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the form block on your collection set like so

```
<%= f.collection_select(:location_1_id, @location, :id, :record_as_string) %>
```

(notice that you are calling the collection_select on the block variable `f`, and NOT passing in the @edge as the first argument).

In addition, because you are creating the object in new (`@edge = Edge.new`), you should just be using in your form, like so

```
<%= form_for( @edge, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
```

(although using `:edge` wasn't the cause of your problems, I suspect it was because you were using `:edge` and `@edge` in the same form. You need to be consistent, use one or the other)

Comment: I had @edge before this. That wasn't working so I tried this.

Comment: Hmm, did you try `:edge` and using `f.collection_select`?